# Using SQL Sub-queries in an INSERT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here are the two tables created:

```
CREATE TABLE category_tbl(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
subcategory varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT nameSubcategory UNIQUE KEY(name, subcategory)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE device(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cid INT DEFAULT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
received DATE,
isbroken BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES category_tbl(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Below is the instruction that was given to me:

```
-- insert the following devices instances into the device table (you should use a subquery to set up foriegn keys referecnes, no hard coded numbers):
-- cid - reference to name: phone subcategory: maybe a tablet?
-- name - Samsung Atlas
-- received - 1/2/1970
-- isbroken - True
```

I'm getting errors on the insert statement below from attempting to use a sub-query within an insert statement. How would you solve this issue?

```
INSERT INTO devices(cid, name, received, isbroken)
VALUES((SELECT id FROM category_tbl WHERE subcategory = 'tablet')  , 'Samsung Atlas', 1/2/1970, 'True');
```

Comment: What errors do you get?  Just eye-balling it, it looks like your subquery could potentially return multiple rows; perhaps try adding `LIMIT 1` to the end of it?

Comment: Otherwise, you could always do `INSERT INTO devices(cid, name, received, isbroken) SELECT id, 'Samsung Atlas', 1/2/1970, 'True' FROM category_tbl WHERE subcategory = 'tablet' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Yes, for some reason, the LIMIT 1 appears to work perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have different table name in `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` so just choose one `device` or `devices`
2. When insert date format use the good one like `DATE('1970-02-01')`
3. When insert boolean - just `TRUE` with no qoutes I beleive.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7180/1

```
INSERT INTO devices(cid, name, received, isbroken)
VALUES((SELECT id FROM category_tbl WHERE subcategory = 'tablet')  , 'Samsung Atlas', DATE('1970-02-01'), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's not possible to use a `SELECT` in an `INSERT ... VALUES ...` statement. The key here is the `VALUES` keyword.</strike> (EDIT: It is actually possible, my bad.)

If you remove the **`VALUES`** keyword, you can use the **`INSERT ... SELECT ...`** form of the INSERT statement statement.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( a, b, c) SELECT 'a','b','c'
```

In your case, you could run a query that returns the needed value of the foreign key column, e.g.

```
SELECT c.id
  FROM category_tbl c
 WHERE c.name = 'tablet'
 ORDER BY c.id
 LIMIT 1
```

If we add some literals in the SELECT list, like this...

```
SELECT c.id              AS `cid`
     , 'Samsung Atlas'   AS `name`
     , '1970-01-02'      AS `received`
     , 'True'            AS `isBroken`
  FROM category_tbl c
 WHERE c.name = 'tablet'
 ORDER BY c.id
 LIMIT 1
```

That will return a "row" that we could insert.  Just precede the SELECT with

```
INSERT INTO device (`cid`, `name`, `received`, `isbroken`)
```

NOTE: The expressions returned by the SELECT are "lined up" with the columns in the column list by *position*, not by name.  The aliases assigned to the expressions in the `SELECT` list are arbitrary, they are basically ignored. They could be omitted, but I think having the aliases assigned makes it easier to understand when we run just the SELECT portion.